# Displaying previously selected answers in the survey questionnaire created using ResearchKit

Tags: ios, swift, researchkit

I am developing an app in Swift, using research kit framework. The answers given by user while taking the survey are being saved in local database. A functionality needs to be implemented in the application, such that when user again starts with the survey he can view the previous selected answers.
Can we set default selected values for the ORKOrderedTask created.

below is the code snippet used:

```
var steps = [ORKStep]()
let questQuestionStepTitle = "What is your quest?"
let textChoices = [
    ORKTextChoice(text: "Create a ResearchKit App", value: 0),
    ORKTextChoice(text: "Seek the Holy Grail", value: 1),
    ORKTextChoice(text: "Find a shrubbery", value: 2)]
let questAnswerFormat: ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat =     ORKAnswerFormat.choiceAnswerFormatWithStyle(.SingleChoice, textChoices: textChoices)
let questQuestionStep = ORKQuestionStep(identifier: "TextChoiceQuestionStep", title: questQuestionStepTitle, answer: questAnswerFormat)
steps += [questQuestionStep]
return ORKOrderedTask(identifier: "SurveyTask", steps: steps)
```

Can we set default selected value for options?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/issues/689

Use solution 2.
Specifically, subclass ordered class and override stepAfterStep.